# How can I do Left Outer Join with Linq when updating an object?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to enhance a person object by doing a join. I want to do a left outer join on firstname and lastname. Then I want to update the person object with a method (this method returns a person object back) I have available and select from there.

The issue I have here is that there is a null reference exception and I'm not sure how to prevent that. If I remove the DefaultIfEmpty I get an inner join but obviously I want the left outer. I know typically you would want to handle nulls, but I'm unsure how to properly do that in this situation.

```cs
person = from p in person
    join epd in enhancedPersonData
        on new { p.firstname, p.lastname} equals new { epd.firstname, epd.lastname} into epdJoin
    from epdj in epdJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select p.UpdatePerson(epdj);
```

I've tried the below but it is just an inner join:

```cs
person = from p in person
    join epd in enhancedPersonData
        on new { p.firstname, p.lastname} equals new { epd.firstname, epd.lastname}
    select p.UpdatePerson(epd);
```

Person:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Firstname{ get; set; }
    public string Lastname{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    
    public Person(string firstname, string lastname){
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

UpdatePerson:

```
public static Person UpdatePerson (this Person schema,
    EnhancedPersonData enhancedPersonData)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(enhancedPersonData.Address)) 
    {
        schema.Address = enhancedPersonData.Address;
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

UpdatePerson:

```
public static Person UpdatePerson (this Person schema,
    EnhancedPersonData enhancedPersonData)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(enhancedPersonData?.Address)) 
    {
        schema.Address = enhancedPersonData.Address;
    }
}
```

Join Code:

```cs
person = from p in person
    join epd in enhancedPersonData
        on new { p.firstname, p.lastname} equals new { epd.firstname, epd.lastname} into epdJoin
    from epdj in epdJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select p.UpdatePerson(epdj);
```

Comment: Linq the q stands for query and is mean to reading data.  It is not meant for writing.  The class objects returned use ByRef so once you retrieve the object you can change properties in the object. by using for loops or get index of the object.  Linq returns an IEnumerable result.

Comment: Also, If you are using a left join, then `epdj` will be `null` if there is no matching person in `enhancedPersonData`. What is the point in updating a person with null:  `p.UpdatePerson(null);`? How is `UpdatePerson` declared? Does it return something, e.g. a Boolean telling if the update was successful or the updated person itself?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I don't want to send in a null to UpdatePerson. UpdatePerson just updates a few properties and returns a Person object back

Comment: @Virt UpdatePerson not returning a Person instance is intentional or mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a left join, then `epdj` will be `null` if there is no matching person in `enhancedPersonData`.

What is the point in updating a person with null:  `p.UpdatePerson(null);`?

Since a class is a reference type, the original person collection will automatically contain the updated persons. It makes no sense to re-assign the returned persons to it. You can safely discard the result of the query, then the left join is no more necessary

```cs
_ = from p in person
    join epd in enhancedPersonData
        on new { p.firstname, p.lastname} equals new { epd.firstname, epd.lastname}
    select p.UpdatePerson(epd);
```

Note that in C# `_` is a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards).

---

Solutions

1. **Remove null reference exception**

   After you have posted your code, I see where your null reference exception occurs. It is in the line

   ```cs
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(enhancedPersonData.Address))
   ```

   If you use left join, then `enhancedPersonData` can be `null`. Therefore change the line to

   ```cs
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(enhancedPersonData?.Address))
   ```
2. **Convert IEnumerable to List**

   Other possible solution: Since `person` is an `IEnumerable<Person>`, it is unknown to me what the real data source is. Is it a collection or the result of a database query? In the latter case my approach (no left join, assign to `_`) won't work. However, you can make it work by declaring `person` as a `List<Person>` instead. Because otherwise, the real data source will be required every time you enumerate the `IEnumerable<Person> person`.

Note that an `IEnumerable<T>` is **not** a collection. It provides a means to enumerate a collection or a data source.

---

Also, the assignment in `UpdatePerson` should be

```cs
schema.Address = enhancedPersonData.Address; // With a lower case enhancedPersonData
```

instead of

```
schema.Address = EnhancedPersonData.Address;
```

otherwise you might be accessing a static property, which of course would have the same value for all objects.

Comment: This causes my inner join to be captured in the _ and then my person collection is no different (objects inside don't seem to get updated).

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing the relevant code (`UpdatePerson` and the declaration of `person`). I assume that persons are a class, not a struct.

Comment: Yeah I apologize. I've tried to give as much context as I can.

The person variable is a collection of Person objects. So really person is IEnumerable<Person>

Essentially I am trying to join 2 IEnumerables one holding Persons, the other holding EnhancedPersonData. I just want to update (using left outer join since I want the original data and the updated data) each Person with the corresponding (firstname/lastname match) EnhancedPersonData

Comment: Please include the code for the Person class or at least the `UpdatePerson` method. Also `Person` must be a class! Structs won't work.

Comment: I added the class and the method

Comment: Ahh I see. The EnhancedPersonData.Address was actually a typo when I brought the problem over to stack, thanks for pointing that out.

Also, thanks for the correction on IEnumerable.

This seems to be what I was looking for, thanks!